# Extend scrollview to fit content SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Hello I’m trying to make the scrollview extent to fit the content.

What i have so far

```
    @IBOutlet var articleScroll: UIScrollView!
    articleTitle.text = defaultValue1
    firstSection.text = defaultValue2


    let fixedWidth = firstSection.frame.size.width
    firstSection.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let newSize = firstSection.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = firstSection.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    firstSection.frame = newFrame;
```

i tried this but it didn’t work

```
articleScroll.contentsize.height = newFrame.height
```

That works fine for the UITextView because its resizes the textview to fit the content. Now i want the scrollview to extent to fit the content. How would i add that?

Comment: If the scroll view will fit its content, what are you going to scroll then?

Comment: I don’t want it to scroll. I have it in a tableview that can already scroll. I already programmed it with parallax and everything to just get rid of the scrollview

Comment: [size of content of UIView](https://github.com/romainmenke/CGRectUnionWithSubviews) Use this recursive function.